# How to set MDC values in threads which are automatically created by the application

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, threadpool, mdc

My Objective is to add a custom message/property value in all the logs generated by the application and display them in console.

In my application I have set the MDC(slf4j) values in all the threads and executors(using Task Decorator) but there are few threads like

***[freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient***

***[ari housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool***

***[nfoReplicator-0] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase***

These threads are created automatically by Spring application and the logs generated by these threads/packages are not able to display the values in MDC

Does anyone know how can I access these threads and all the threads which are automatically generated by the application so that I can set the MDC context values in them.

Thanks in advance.